# Firebase my "Default GCP resource location" is not found

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using **firebase** for my own website, but when I want to choose my **location** (I'm from *Iraq*, ***western Asia***) to complete "Project settings", I found that my **location** is not exist in the **list of "Default GCP resource location".** Is there a problem? Or ***firebase doesn't support western Asia countries?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations) as the source of truth about supported Firebase product regions.

You can see that [RTDB is supported](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations#rtdb-locations) in us-central1, europe-west1, and asia-southeast1.

Firestore uses your project's default resource location.  Its [list of supported regions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations#location-r) does not include western Asia.